# ASP.NET MVC Update Set Class Property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, object

I have a "ContentModel" class. And the my model has a Category property and the property relation to "CategoryModel" class.. When i create a new content i get category id from query string and i set "Category" property. But how can i get category prop from form(view) when post is submit.

```
        //controller
        ContentModel contentmodel;
        if (id > 0)
        {
            contentmodel = db.Content.Find(id);
        }
        else
        {
            ContentCategoryModel contentCat = db.Category.Find(catId) as ContentCategoryModel;

            contentmodel = new ContentModel();
            contentmodel.Category = contentCat;
        }

        ViewBag.Tab = tab;

        if (contentmodel == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(contentmodel);



        ------------
        //in view
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ContentId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Category)
```

Comment: `model.Category` looks like a complex property so it should be `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Category.Id)` if you want to post back `Category.ID`

Comment: yep, thank you. i've solved it a similar way...